# Can't get my error message from json ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, error-handling

I use the `$.ajax()` jquery to do some ajax calls.  Recently i have one ajax call that returns json formatted string for a successful call.  In my server php code, if there is a problem, i just return a string data ( `die("nothing found in database");` ) , non-json formatted that is a message explaining the problem.  The ajax call works correctly, but I am having a hard time getting that string response.

Here is the javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "check.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        row_id : row_id
    },
    async: false
}).done(function(data) {
    check = data;
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, msg ){
    $('#dialog').html("<p>"+textStatus+"</p>");
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                $( this ).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

None of the 3 variables in the `.fail()` function give me that string response I sent from the server.  That `textStatus` just gives me "parseerror".  The `msg` variable give me: "Unexpected token T".  What I want is just the plain string that I sent from the .php file with the `die()` function.  I tested to make sure the php is sending the string correctly.  Does anyone know how I should get my string data response?

Maybe this isn't the correct way to handle this.  I am thinking because there really wasn't an error with the ajax call, its just I chose to return a normal string instead of JSON, which is a signal that there is a problem.

Comment: add an `alert(textStatus)` inside the `fail` and see what you are getting. It may be failing the `html()` line if the value is invalid within a `<p>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **dataType: "json",** from ajax call and use JSON.parse() on the response string before use.
Because if parsing of JSON is issue then you would get error here.

But I suspect if that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you can't really display your non-json string?

In .fail function I'm used to write like this, and it has always worked:

```
 .fail(function(data) { /* handle data response */ });
```

And simply display the data. Do a **console.log**(**data**) to see if it's displaying what you want.

**EDIT**: Of course, in PHP do some others tests too, like **return "Your message here.";**, **echo** 'Your message'; etc.